# StartActivityForResult from Fragmnet

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-fragments

I have two ImageView and two buttons. When button pressed - Dialog started. Positive answer - picture from galery, negative - from camera. First i write this in Activity(this code is work good):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    String path = null;
    if (DialogFlag == 0) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case GALLERY_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
                Log.d("myLogs", path);
                if (btnID == 1) {
                    pathOne = path;
                    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOne);
                    ivOne.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                    one = bmImg;
                } else {
                    pathTwo = path;
                    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathTwo);
                    ivTwo.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                    two = bmImg;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    if (DialogFlag == 1) {
        Uri uri;
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
                    Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
                    path = uri.toString();
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }
            Log.d("myLogs", path);
            if (btnID == 1) {
                pathOne = path;
                Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOne);
                ivOne.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                one = bmImg;
            } else {
                pathTwo = path;
                Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathTwo);
                ivTwo.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                two = bmImg;
            }

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case IDD_TWO_BUTTONS:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Зображення з ")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Галереї",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                DialogFlag = 0;
                                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,
                                        GALLERY_REQUEST);
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                .setNeutralButton("Камери",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                DialogFlag = 1;
                                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                        CAMERA_RESULT);
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }

                )
                .setNegativeButton("Відміна",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }

                );

        return builder.create();
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when i try to make this in fragment i get some problem.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
    MyDialogFragment frag = new MyDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.plus_icon)
            .setTitle(title).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Intent i =getActivity().getIntent();
                i.putExtra("key", true);
                getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 101, i);
            }
        }
    )
    .setNegativeButton("NO",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
               //AddExerciseFragment.doNegativeClick();
                Intent i =getActivity().getIntent();
                i.putExtra("key", false);

                getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 101, i);
            }
        }
    )
            .create();
}

}
```

onActivityResult in AddExerciseFragment

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

    String path = null;
    switch (requestCode) {
    case DIALOG_FRAGMENT:
        boolean check = imageReturnedIntent.getBooleanExtra("key", true);
        if (check) {
            doPositiveClick();
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
                Log.d("myLogs", path);
                if (btnID == 1) {
                    pathOne = path;
                    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOne);
                    ivOne.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                    one = bmImg;
                } else {

                    pathTwo = path;
                    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathTwo);
                    ivTwo.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                    two = bmImg;
                }
            }
        } else {
            doNegativeClick();
            Uri uri;

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
                    Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
                    path = uri.toString();
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }
            Log.d("myLogs", path);
            if (btnID == 1) {
                pathOne = path;
                Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOne);
                ivOne.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                one = bmImg;
            } else {
                pathTwo = path;
                Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathTwo);
                ivTwo.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                two = bmImg;
            }

        }
        break;
    }
}

public void doPositiveClick() {
    DialogFlag = 0;

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    // dialog.cancel();

}

public void doNegativeClick() {
    DialogFlag = 1;
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_RESULT);

}

void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment
            .newInstance(R.string.name);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

But i have next:

1. If i want to set image from galery-it start galery, but i can not choose picture there
2. From camera i can set picture only once and only for one imageView
3. when i am in galery and press button "back" - i get error.

Comment: Add the error you are getting to the question.

Comment: What error are you getting? Why can't you choose? Can you see but can't choose or something else?

Comment: First - i press OK, and start Galery. I choose picture -> i see 1 second white screen -> and galery is loading again -> i choose picture once more and get outOfMemory

Comment: if you get outOfMemory you need to scale down your btimap. your app is exceeding the heap size allocated. Scale down your bitmap.

Comment: but when i use it in Activity - all is good, why?